# Could you look at my code, I don't know what's wrong with it

Tags: python

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open("mbox-short.txt")
inp = fh.read()
count = 0
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        continue
    count = count + 1
    c = float(count)
    print(len(inp))
    average = inp / c
print("Average spam confidence:", average)
```

The code above should write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:

X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475

These lines should be counted and the floating point values from each of the lines extracted to compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below. How could a possible code look like without the usage of the sum() function or a variable named sum in the solution? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your loop attempts to iterate over an empty file handle; you've already read all there is to read with `input = fh.read()`.

Comment: Your question says something is wrong with your code, yet there is no error. Please clarify

Comment: You may want to check what your code is actually doing. For example, ``inp`` is file content (a string), ``c`` is a number, yet the code tries to calculate ``inp / c``. Likewise, nothing ever attempts to read the "floating point values from each of the lines" – it merely converts the count of lines to float.

Comment: Can you clarify why you do not want to use the builtin ``sum`` or a variable of the same name? Do you have any other such restrictions?

Comment: You never use the variable `fname`, which is supposed to have the name of a file. Instead, you hard-code the filename "`mbox-short.txt`".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over an empty object.

The line `inp = fh.read()` has exhausted the fh object and it has become set to None

Comment: ``for line in inp:`` will iterate *by character*, not by line.